# ¿Cómo copiar un registro de una hoja de excel a otra hoja según el valor que tenga una columna?

Tags: excel

Tengo una hoja de excel llamada `Maestra` en la cuál ingreso diariamente los recuentos de bacterias encontrados en los análisis microbiológicos, esta hoja contiene los registros de cada máquina durante el día.

¿Cómo puedo hacer mediante el uso de macros qué cuando ingrese un registro en la hoja `Maestra`, si ingreso un registro para la máquina `A`, este registro se me copie a la hoja `A`, si ingreso un registro para la máquina `B`, este se me copie a la hoja `B`, si ingreso un registro para la máquina `C`, este se me copie a la hoja `C`?

Adjunto imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola E. Guerrero, por favor incluye el código que has intentado hasta el momento

Comment: creo que lo que quiere hacer alomejor asi se entiende mejor en la primera hoja tiene una celda(columna) que se llama MAQUINA, si en una celda de esa columna se pone una A o B o C esa fila se tiene que copiar a las hojas A,B o C segun corresponda (o eso creo), sin contar las celdas de la primera fila que tiene los titulos. Saludos

Comment: no se si esto es lo que buscar pero creo que te puede ayudar https://exceltotal.com/macro-para-copiar-datos-de-una-hoja-otra-en-excel/

Comment: Tiene que ser necesariamente con una macro? Esto lo puedes resolver por ejemplo con una tabla dinámica.

Comment: ¿Haz intentado usar la grabadora de macros del propio Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno, esta comunidad está iniciando y es importante crear un buen ambiente, pero, sin olvidar las reglas. Acá se contestan las preguntas que tengas en cuanto a tu trabajo, principalmente programación y computación, acá no le hacemos el trabajo a la gente, aunque siempre hay una buena disposición de ayudar a los demás.

Trata de buscar la información que necesitas, has el intento de hacerlo por ti mismo, y luego de eso, comparte el esfuerzo que hiciste junto con las preguntas que puedas tener, y así te orientamos, para que puedas aprender mas acerca del tema.

Y como te dije, siempre hay buena disposición para ayudar.

En el código de la hoja llamada "Maestra" agrega esta función,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(Click derecho en la pestaña, "`Ver código`")

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AcSht As Worksheet
    Dim shtV As Worksheet
    Dim r

    If Target.Column = 2 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        r = Target.Row
        Set AcSht = ActiveSheet
        Set shtV = Sheets(Target.Value)

        MoverDatos AcSht, shtV, Target
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Luego en un módulo normal agregas este otro código:

```
Sub MoverDatos(main As Worksheet, sht1 As Worksheet, rng As Range)
    Dim r1
    Dim r2

    r1 = rng.Row
    Rows(r1 & ":" & r1).Copy
    sht1.Activate
    r2 = Evaluate("Counta(A:A)") + 1
    Rows(r2 & ":" & r2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    main.Activate
End Sub
```

### Importante

Puedes meter los datos normalmente, en la hoja, excepto el dato de la columna `B`, cuando agregues cualquier cosa allí, se va a ejecutar la primera función, y va a llamar la macro `MoverDatos`, si agregas algo distinto a `A`, `B` o `C`, entonces tendrás un error en la ejecución, por que ese debe ser siempre el nombre de las hojas donde quieres enviar los datos.

Si cambias la columna donde pones la máquina, debe de cambiar el número de la columna, `If Target.Column = 2 Then` por el número correcto.

Comment: Los tres primeros párrafos sobran, no están respondiendo a la pregunta. Por favor, bórralos de la respuesta, y si quieres añádelos como un comentario en la pregunta original.